# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, lda

```
 topics_nr = [15]


alpha= [(50/topics_nr)] 
beta = [0.01]
dtm=()


lda = the_LDA(topics_nr, alpha, beta, dtm)
```

I run and get the following error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

I am not able to resolve this issue
Please help

Comment: You are trying to divide 50 by the list [15] which is not a defined operation. What do you expect to accomplish?

Comment: Why have you defined **alpha** in a `list` ?

Comment: I want to divide the number 50 by the number 15. However, when I enter topics_nr= 15, I get the following error- Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: You're not entering `topics_nr=15` you're entering `topics_nr=[15]`. The former assigns an integer and the latter assigns a list.